# Simple Chrome Extension - Selection To Tab Via Context Menu

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Hey I'm looking for some help with a really simple Chrome Extension I'd like to get working. The extension is supposed to grab selected text, and then, through a context menu open a new tab with a URL looking like this: *http://dict.cc/?s=selectedText*

This is what I've got so far:

The Manifest.JSON:

```
 {  
 "name": "QuickTranslate",  
 "version": "0.1",  
 "manifest_version": 2,  
 "background": {"persistent": true, "scripts": ["bg.js"]},  
 "permissions": ["contextMenus"]  
 }
```

In my understanding, so far, everything should be just fine. Just FYI, I really don't know much about Java Script, let alone Chrome Extensions.

The bg.js:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({  
   title: "Translate '%s'",  
   contexts: ["selection"],  
   onclick: function search() {  
   chrome.tabs.create ({url: "http://dict.cc"}) },  
});
```

Now this is where I'm stuck. I'm sure there is some (easy?) way to add the selected text to the url. '%s' did not work, at least not for me.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`search()` gets called with the object [*OnClickData*](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#type-OnClickData) as its first argument, and the selected text is stored in the property *selectionText*.

This will work:

```
onclick: function search(OnClickData) {  
  chrome.tabs.create ({url: "http://dict.cc/?s=" + OnClickData.selectionText}) }
```